# How to fix Expression Blend packages failing to load?

Tags: wpf, package, blend

After reinstalling Visual Studio (and all of its components), I ran into an issue with Expression Blend, which stopped to work. Upon starting Expression Blend, the following error is displayed:

[image]

When trying to "Create new project", no project templates are shown.
Finally, when I tried to open an existing WPF project, error messages started to show, stating that various packages did not load correctly:

[image]

Reading ActivityLog.xml was not very helpful. I attached it here: [ActivityLog.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu7sjqrjmxcfywp/ActivityLog.xml?dl=0)

I did not have any issues with blend before I performed a reinstall, so it must have damaged Blend files.

I tried running Visual Studio installer to repair it, but it did not help.

How can I fully reset Expression Blend settings, or fully reinstall/repair it to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. To resolve such problems with Visual Studio or Blend, simply delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}\ComponentModelCache` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Blend\{version}\ComponentModelCache` (respectively), then restart your Visual Studio or Blend.

Solution found [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800087/getting-error-microsoft-visualstudio-editor-implementation-editorpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)