# "The 'Visual Studio XML Editor Package' did not load correctly."

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend

Hey guys I was starting Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio when this error came up:
[image]

The XML file referenced in the error thing:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ovSgvaWLtAEHjrxtWoCXt8Ei33YANPqa/view?usp=sharing.

Does anyone know what happened here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For package did not load correctly, you can try to click **Repair** in the Visual Studio installer to repair it. If it doesn't work, you can try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217306/how-to-fix-expression-blend-packages-failing-to-load/38217695#38217695).