# Visual Studio XML Editor Package didn't load correctly (Blend for Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition)

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio, blend

I have problem with Blend for Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. This means , I make a project and I see this message. This is in Polish Language but this problem is like this in ["The 'Visual Studio XML Editor Package' did not load correctly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922260/the-visual-studio-xml-editor-package-did-not-load-correctly). This is the same problem and I want to find a solution. I try to repair and re-install but it didn't help. I try to delete the ComponentModelCache but it doesn't work. How to solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh0i9.png)
Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with different strange package names (VSPackage and Package).
I deleted the entire folder that contains AppData for Visual Studio 2022: `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_355cec58\`.
I reinstalled the VS extension that I thought have caused the issue.
This did not help. Then I repaired the VS 2022 and restarted the computer. The issue is gone.

You can also see what error is logged in ActivityLog.xml that is present in the screenshot of your exception.